# How to resolve "Components directory not found" warning in nuxt speedlit module?

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to use [**nuxt speedlit module**](https://nuxt-speedkit.grabarzundpartner.dev/) in my nuxt-2 project. when I install that, it does not create Components directory in my **.nuxt** folder. So after running `npm run dev`, I see these two warnings in my command line:

[image: Nuxt speedkit warning]

I think that module must create and fill these directory automatically. But it does not do that. So I tried to access the source codes of that components according to [the docs](https://nuxt-speedkit.grabarzundpartner.dev/guide/options/#available-components). But those links also don't give me anything (like [this link](https://github.com/GrabarzUndPartner/nuxt-speedkit/blob/main/lib/components/SpeedkitLayer.vue)).
Because of the problems I explained, when I want to use that components in my nuxt template part like these codes:

```html
<template>
<speedkit-layer>
      <div>
        <p>Sorry, but you will have a limited user experience due to a…</p>

        <ul style="padding: 0; list-style: none;">
          <!-- Displayed when javascript is disabled. -->
          <li id="nuxt-speedkit-message-nojs">
            disabled javascript
          </li>
          <!-- Displayed when browser does not support. -->
          <li id="nuxt-speedkit-message-unsupported-browser">
            outdated browser
          </li>
          <!-- Displayed when connection bandwidth is too low. -->
          <li id="nuxt-speedkit-message-reduced-bandwidth">
            reduced-bandwidth
          </li>
          <!-- Displayed when user hardware are not sufficient.  -->
          <li id="nuxt-speedkit-message-weak-hardware">
            weak hardware
          </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Button to hide the layer with no javascript -->
        <button id="nuxt-speedkit-button-init-nojs">
          <label for="nuxt-speedkit-layer-close">
            Apply without js
          </label>
        </button>

        <!-- Button for use without javascript and with fonts -->
        <button id="nuxt-speedkit-button-init-reduced-view">
          <label for="nuxt-speedkit-layer-close">
            Apply without scripts
          </label>
        </button>

        <!-- Button for activate javascript by bad connection or browser support -->
        <button id="nuxt-speedkit-button-init-app">
          Apply with all Features
        </button>
      </div>
      
        <!-- some other html tags -->
        
</speedkit-layer>
</template>
```

I get this error in my browser console:

[image: nuxt-speed-kit-browser error]

Could any one please help me to solve this issue? I am using nuxt version `2.17.1` and nuxt speedkit version `2.1.2` and node version `14.19.0` in my project.